# Questions about a proof of the existence of the Lagrange polynomial

Tags: proof-explanation, lagrange-interpolation

In my question I am referring to the proof, that can be found [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/lagrange-interpolation/).

There $P_j(x)$ is defined as : $P_j(x) = \frac{f(x)}{(x-x_j)f'(x_j)}$, where $f(x) = (x-x_1)\dots(x-x_n)$

Then, supposedly, $P(x) = 1 $ if $x \in B:= \{x_1 , \dots, x_n \}$  - but how/why?

Using this, I would get: $$1 = P(x_1) = \frac{(x_1-x_2)\dots(x_1-x_n)}{f'(x_1)} \Rightarrow f'(x_1) = (x_1-x_2)\dots(x_1-x_n) $$

which looks to me like some sort of basic identity.

I also tried looking at $f'(x)$ in general as: $f'(x) = x' (x-x_2)\dots(x-x_n) - x_1 ((x-x_2)\dots(x-x_n))' \overset{\mbox{?}}{\Rightarrow} x_1 (x-x_2)\dots(x-x_n) = 0 $ if $x = x_1$

I don't really see how this steps follow, (if at all) - thus I would be happy about any constructive comment/answer regarding the construction of the $P_j(x)$ and the role $f'(x)$ has in it, as I find that the confusing part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have, 
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=(x-x_1)'(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_n)+(x-x_1)\,[(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_n)]'\\ \ \\
&=(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_n)+(x-x_1)\,[(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_n)]'.
\end{align}
When you evaluate at $x_1$, the second term is zero, so 
$$
f'(x_1)=(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)\cdots(x_1-x_n). 
$$

Comment: Writing it like you did, it becomes trivial - however one clarification is needed: First I decided write out the product of $(x-x_1)$ and $(x-x_2)\dots(x-x_n)$ and then derivate, which I could then not resolve (as in my question above.) How/Why does this go wrong/not helpful? Maybe it does not go wrong, but is not as intuitive as your approach.

Comment: I noticed my error - wrongly applied the product rule.....